# React State returns empty array when accessed within a specific function, but a full array when accessed immediately before and after

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am creating a web app that allows you to search for Spotify tracks and add them to a playlist. I have created an array of `<Track />` components called `playlistTracks` using useState. In my addSong function, I am trying to implement a check to see if the track already exists in the playlist so you can't add a duplicate, so I am calling `playlistTracks.some()` to iterate through the array and set `trackExists`to true if the track already exists in the playlist. My problem is that the `playlistTracks` state is always empty when this function is called, even when I have already added songs and they are visibly rendered on the playlist section of the web app. I know it is empty because I call `console.log("Current playlist tracks:", playlistTracks.map(track => track.props.accessKey));` inside the method and it returns an empty array.

addSong is called from the onClick event of a `<p>` component on each Track.

Here is a snippet of my code with all irrelevant lines removed.

```
function App() {

const [playlistTracks, setPlaylistTracks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Current playlist tracks after update:", playlistTracks.map(track => track.props.accessKey));
  setAccuratePlaylistTracks(playlistTracks);
}, [playlistTracks]);

const addSong = useCallback((name,artist,album, albumCover, songId) =>{

  console.log("Current playlist tracks:", playlistTracks.map(track => track.props.accessKey));

const trackExists = playlistTracks.some((track) => 
  track.props.accessKey ===songId
)

if(!trackExists){
  setPlaylistTracks((prev) => [
    ...prev,
    <Track 
    key = {songId} 
    accessKey = {songId} 
    song = {name} 
    artist = {artist} 
    album = {album} 
    albumCover = {albumCover} 
    isAdd = {false} 
    removeSong = {removeSong}
    />
  ]);
  }else{
    console.log('track already in playlist');
  }
},[playlistTracks]);

return (
    
      <ResultsSection trackList = {trackList} playlistTracks = {playlistTracks} />
  );
}
```

```
const ResultsSection = ({trackList, playlistTracks}) => {
    
    return(
            <Playlist playlistTracks = {playlistTracks}/>
    );
}
```

```
const Playlist = ({playlistTracks}) =>{

    return (
            <ul className = {styles.playlistTracks}>{playlistTracks}</ul>
    )
}
```

```
const Track = (props) =>{
    
const [trackName, setTrackName] = useState(props.song)

    const [artist, setArtist] = useState(props.artist)
    const [album, setAlbum] = useState(props.album)
    const [albumPic, setAlbumPic] = useState(props.albumCover)
    const [isAdd, setAdd] = useState(true);
    const [songId, setSongId] = useState(props.accessKey);
   
useEffect(()=>{
    if(!props.isAdd){
        
        setAdd(false);
    }
},[])
    

    const addHandler = () =>{
        console.log('ADD HANDLER');
        props.addSong(trackName, artist, album, albumPic, songId)
    }

    return(
            {isAdd
            ?<p id = {styles.add} onClick={addHandler}>+</p>
            : <p id={styles.add} onClick={() => props.removeSong(props.accessKey)}>-</p>
}
    );
}
```

I suspected it might be an asynchronous issue, so I created a `useEffect` that prints the current state of the `playlistTracks` array after each rerender of the app component. It prints a full array immediately before and after the addSong method is called. Per the advice of chatGPT, I also tried using `useCallback` on the addSong function, which did not change anything (this is the current state of the code, I was having the same issue before I made it a useCallback). There is no where else in my code where I set the state of playlistTracks. The current functionality of the code is that it will add the track to the playlist and render it on the screen even if it already exists in the array, and give me a warning that two elements in the array have the same key.

Thank you for the help and please let me know if there is any way I can improve this question.

Comment: Tangential, but it's rarely a good idea (or necessary) to keep components in state.

Comment: By "rarely" this effectively means never. It's a React anti-pattern to store JSX in state. You should instead store the data and render the JSX from that data in state.

Comment: Is it still okay to create an array of <Tracks /> as long as I don't store them in state? As in, I could store the data in state and then in the <ResultsSection /> I could create an array from the state data and then render that array.